# ccny_rgbd with vo+mapping slow, map disappears

Tags: ros, mapping, ccny-rgbd, ccny-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Dryanovski/and those who have used the ccny_rgbd,

I am using ROS fuerte and ubuntu 12.04 on an i5 Dell laptop. I have followed the instructions given to launch your method, the visual_odometry is quite fast. However, when I launch the vo+mapping.launch, It is extremely slow and the alignment is really bad. Also the parts of the map that are not viewed disappear after a very short time. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or is this how it is. I was hoping to build a map similar to the video you posted with a similiar performance.

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

Khalid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55166/ccny_rgbd-with-vo+mapping-slow,-map-disappears/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The map disappears in the sense that rviz only shows the last X seconds of published keyframes. The keyframes are stored in the memory of the keyframe_mapper, and you can always request to publish them using the `/publish_keyframes` service.

Depending on your graphics card, visualizing the keyframe point clouds can eat up a lot of resources. Have you tried turning the Keyframe view off in rviz (or setting the timeout to something smaller)?

Could you post the output of VO in the console? It should be able to tell you how much computation time is taken for each step.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fersarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3210/fersarr/) on 2013-05-02**:
Hi! How do we change the X in "last X seconds"? In my case it seems to be even less than a second :S

**Comment by [fersarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3210/fersarr/) on 2013-05-02**:
never mind, found it. Just in case someone is looking for this too: on rviz click on keyframes and change decay time to some value greater than zero